# Can we join tables in on-premise SQL Server database to tables in Delta tables in Azure Delta lake? what are my options

Tags: sql, azure, join, cloud, relational-database

I am archiving rows that are older than a year into ADLSv2 as delta tables, when there is a need to report on that data, I need to join archived data with some tables existing on on-premise database. Is there a way we can do a join without re-hydrating from or hydrating data to cloud?

Comment: Possibly you might look at connecting with Polybase

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this task by using **Azure Data Factory.**

> Azure Data Factory (ADF) is a fully managed, serverless data integration
> service. Visually integrate data sources with more than 90 built-in,
> maintenance-free connectors at no added cost. Easily construct ETL and
> ELT processes code-free in an intuitive environment or write your own
> code.

Firstly, you need to install the Self-hosted Integration Runtime in your local machine to access the on-premises SQL Server in ADF. To accomplish this, refer [Connect to On-premises Data in Azure Data Factory with the Self-hosted Integration Runtime](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5812/connect-to-onpremises-data-in-azure-data-factory-with-the-selfhosted-integration-runtime-part-1/).

As you have archived the data in ADLS, you need to change the **Access tier** of that container from **Cold -> Hot** in order to retrieve the data in ADF.

Later, create a **Linked Service** using Self-hosted IR which you have created. Create a **Dataset** using this Linked Service to access the on-premises database.

Similarly, create a **Linked Service** using default Azure IR. Create a **Dataset** using this Linked Service to access the data from ADLS.

Now, you also require a destination database where you will store the data after join. If you are storing it in same on-premises database, you can use the existing Linked Service but you need to create a new Dataset mentioning the destination table name.

Once all this configuration done, create a **Data Flow activity pipeline in ADF.**

> Mapping data flows are visually designed data transformations in Azure
> Data Factory. Data flows allow data engineers to develop data
> transformation logic without writing code. The resulting data flows
> are executed as activities within Azure Data Factory pipelines that
> use scaled-out Apache Spark clusters.

Learn more about Mapping data flow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview).

**Finally**, in data-flow activity, your sources will be on-premises dataset and ADLS dataset which you have created above. You will be using [join transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join) to combine data from two sources. The output stream will include all columns from both sources matched based on a join condition.

The [sink transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink) will take your destination dataset where the data will be stored as an output.

Comment: does self hosted IR support data flow? I thought it only supports data movement.

Comment: Data flow will run on azure IR only. Self hosted IR will fetch your data from on-premises database.

Comment: Can we push down the filters when fetching data from on-prem database? or do we have to get all the data first and then apply filters with data flow?

Comment: Yes, you can run SQL queries or stored procedure on your data and fetch only the required table/columns.

Comment: I haven't gone down this route, I tried accessing delta table as an external table in synapse server less and tried to access it from on-prem SQL using linked server, it seemed to be working except for an authentication issue I ran into, which I will work on few days later.